# Piranha CMS: Problem with custom block in manager interface

Tags: piranha-cms

I am trying to add a custom block. I followed the steps in following two links:
http://piranhacms.org/docs/extensions/blocks
and
http://piranhacms.org/docs/manager-extensions/resources

In the CMS manager, I added the custom block to a page, but the block content is empty. Looks like the Vue.js didn't get associated to the custom block. I have set the block component attribute to the Vue.js.

I added the Vue.js by calling below method in the startup. Did I miss something to create a custom block?

```
App.Modules.Get<Piranha.Manager.Module>().Scripts.Add("~/assets/js/myscripts.js");
```

Comment: Hi! Can you verify in your browser that you custom script gets loaded and that there are no JavaScript errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 2):

Move your "mycustomblock.js" file to the folder "wwwroot/js/" instead of the default "assets/js/". That way the file will be visible to Vue.js

Something is not working with the assets folder, probably it cannot be reached by Vue.js 
after the Project is compiled. I had the same problem and this solution worked for me.

```
    void Configure in Startup.cs will then look something like this (I simplified the syntax a bit compared to the documentation):

    App.Modules.Manager().Scripts.Add("~/js/mycustomblock.js");
```

Adding a custom block and many other tasks have been difficult for me. Trial and error, and no knowledgebase to fall back on. The documentation is a fantastic start, and "Step by step" guides would be a good idea for the future (but I guess time is very limited).